# Zip all by all in two lists

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
c = zip(a, b)
print c
```

This gives me an output of:

```
[(1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'), (3, 'test3'), (4, 'test4'), (5, 'test5')]
```

What I actually want though looks like this:

```
[(1, 'test1'), (1, 'test2'), (1, 'test3'), (1, 'test4'), (1, 'test5')
 (2, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'), (2, 'test3'), (2, 'test4'), (2, 'test5')
 (3, 'test1'), (3, 'test2'), (3, 'test3'), (3, 'test4'), (3, 'test5')
 (4, 'test1'), (4, 'test2'), (4, 'test3'), (4, 'test4'), (4, 'test5')
 (5, 'test1'), (5, 'test2'), (5, 'test3'), (5, 'test4'), (5, 'test5')]
```

Can anyone tell me how I should amend the above code to get my desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.product([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']):
    print i
```

Comment: A cartesian merge is how i would have done it in SQL, but I wasn't sure how to go about it in Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `for` loop,

```
c = []
for i in a:
    for s in b:
        c.append((i, s))
```

or the equivalent list comprehension,

```
c = [(i,s) for i in a for s in b]
```

or the ever-useful `itertools.product`,

```
import itertools

c = list(itertools.product(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension works here:

```
 >>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 >>> b = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
 >>> [ (x,y) for x in a for y in b ]
 [(1, 'test1'), (1, 'test2'), (1, 'test3'), (1, 'test4'), (1, 'test5'), (2, 'test1'), (2, 'test2'), (2, 'test3'), (2, 'test4'), (2, 'test5'), (3, 'test1'), (3, 'test2'), (3, 'test3'), (3, 'test4'), (3, 'test5'), (4, 'test1'), (4, 'test2'), (4, 'test3'), (4, 'test4'), (4, 'test5'), (5, 'test1'), (5, 'test2'), (5, 'test3'), (5, 'test4'), (5, 'test5')]
```